# Which is one better for static const char* or static const string for declaring static variables

Tags: c++, c++14

I am developing cross-platform C++ library. I wanted a better way of defining my string constants which will be used throughout the program. Which one is better static const char * or static const std::string?
Does constexpr make any of them better over the old declaration?

```
static const char *str = "hello world";
```

vs

```
static const string str = "hello world";
```

Why I need this:
My program might have to initialise a lot of static variable of string literals type before starting app. And i can't get away with static variables because they are used in the entire file. If i have to increase the performance, but reducing time of static variable initialisation. Ideally i would want most of things to happen at compile time rather than runtime. which one would be better choice?

Comment: What 's the usage of static here?

Comment: better with respect to what? interoperability with c or in terms of avoiding out-of-bounds access? ;)

Comment: It depends on what you're doing to do with it.

Comment: The key is what do you need the string to do? Will you ever need to get the length? Do you want the convenience of `string.length()` or do you want to use `strlen()`. For that matter you can `#define STRCONST1 "My String Const"` and so on. It depends on how you want to use it throughout your code. Obviously, `char *` will be less compiler and resource intensive, a `#define` even less so, but `std::string` offers a lot neither of those provide for little extra cost.

Comment: You forgot `string_view` which supersedes `const char*` in modern C++ (and which works with `constexpr` which you should use in that case).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin  i don't need strlen(). Most of the time this it is used for comparing with other strings or a new string object is created with this variable.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher, string_view is c++17, we are using c++14

Comment: @user463035818, avoiding delay of startup time of app, since static variables are initialised before app is started.

Comment: In the second one you are assigning a `char const*` to a `std::string`. Why not use the new syntax that allows you to specify a `std::string` literal.  `static const string str = "hello world"s;` (note the last s) https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Answer (score 4):

Usually, `std::string` is good but in any case it depends on what you want to do. There is no absolute silver bullet here. `std::string` has a constructor and will call `new/malloc` for example (when SSO small string optimization can't be applied). If this is undesirable for any reason, go with const char*.

It depends also on where it 's to be used. If this is a HWND window title for example and the main use is with Windows API functions, it won't differ if you use std::string's c_str() method all the time.

All this is to advise that there is no 100% preference for one or another.

The usage or not of `static` is a different discussion.

Comment: My program might have to initialise a lot of static variable of string literals type before starting of main. And i can't get away with static variables because they are used in the entire file.

Comment: `std::string has a constructor and will call new/malloc for example` that statement is incorrect. Every modern implementation implements SSO (small string optimization) which is stored on the stack

Answer (score 2):

It will depend on what you do with these variables. For example, take a look at this:

```
void do_stuff(std::string const&);

void stuff() {
    while(/* some condition */) {
        do_stuff(constant); // very hot loop
    }
}
```

Let's take the two ways of defining the `constant` variable:

```
constexpr auto constant = "value";          // (1)
auto const constant = std::string{"value"}; // (2)
```

In the case of the hot loop, if you take `(1)`, it will create a string each time. If the string value it long enough, it can cause allocation. Then `(2)` is better for that case.

On the other hand, if you refactor your code to something like this:

```
void do_stuff(std::string_view);

void stuff() {
    while(/* some condition */) {
        do_stuff(constant); // very hot loop
    }
}
```

Then your program will be much faster with `(1)`, since no dynamic allocation will occur. Your program will refer to the original read only data of your program.

Answer (score 0):

With modern `C++` I would use `std::string_view`.

If you do need it to be `std::string` then the best option is to define it as a static local variable in a function, so it is lazily initialized upon the first request.

```
/* inline or not */
std::string const& get_that_string() {
    static std::string const str { "value" };
    return value;
}
```

Comment: This approach might not scale up, if have good number of static variables. writing function for everything might be over-kill

Comment: use string_view then

Answer (score -1):

Unless there are known problems in your specific code base with using `std::string`, I strongly suggest using `std::string`.

```
static std::string const str = "hello world";
```

Answer (score -2):

In general you should prefer `std::string` over `char*`. `static` has nothing to do with it.

Comment: the question is about declaring static variables...so `static` does have soemthing to do with it ;)